# onActivityResult never call when Capture image from Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three fragment in one Activity. In second fragment i called Intent for capture image and want to save it on same fragment, but `onActivityResult()` method not called.

Comment: Have override _onActivityResult()_ in activity too? Also show code.

Answer (score 0):

just in your `MainActivity` write this :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

         YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();

        fragment.onActivityResult(100, resultCode, data);

    }
```

when in your fragment have `startActivityForResult(intent, 100);`  above code works!

and in your fragment `onActivityResult` you should do that you want.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //do something here..
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: in parent Activity getting onActivityResult( 65637, -1, data)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65637, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.isystem/com.example.isystem.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: when in your fragment have  `startActivityForResult(intent, 100);` above code work! and in your fragment `onActivityResult` you should do that you want. ( if (requestCode == 100) 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) //Do somthing here)

Comment: I completed my answer ..try it

Comment: please show code in your question

Comment: Fragment A{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);}

Comment: don't write `getActivity` before  `startActivityForResult`....make sure your `REQUEST_CODE ` is equals to that wrote in `onActivityResult` ( for exmple both be 100)

Comment: If you want to check your issue, please enter your full code in the text of your question.